# Parametrization and Projections

Tags: matrices, parametrization, projection-matrices

I have a question over this problem that I've encountered. I don't know how to solve it.

Let $\ell$ be the line parametrized as $(t, 2t+1, 3t+2)$ and let $P$ be the plane with equation
$x+y+z = 1.$
(a) Prove that the matrix
$\mathbf{A} =  \begin{pmatrix} -2 & -2 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0& -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $maps all points on line $\ell$ to points on plane $P$.

(b) Prove that the matrix
$\mathbf{B} =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 3 & 3 & -1 \\ 5& 5 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$maps all points on plane $P$ to points on line $\ell$.

So far, I've tried just plugging points in and such, but it's not really a solid proof. Can someone help me please?

Edit 1: So far, I have transformed the parametrized line into a vector, to multiply the matrix with. However, I don't know how to move on.

Comment: Compute the images of the two maps, or simply apply them to the parametric forms of the line/plane and see what you get.

Comment: @amd, how do I "simply apply them to the parametric forms?" Do I treat the parametric as a matrix, and multiply them together?

Comment: The parametric forms of the equations for the line and plane are simply vectors with one or two variables.